# Language file not loading - Wordpress Child Theme

Tags: wordpress, localization

I'm trying to add a Dutch translation to a Wordpress theme.
I have edited .pot file (inside the theme) with POedit, and saved nl_NL .po and .mo (without any issues).

Naturally, I've made languages directory in my childtheme (called charityhub-child).

I have changed my code in the most basic form (taken from Wordpress Code reference).

My functions.php looks like this:

```
function wpdocs_child_theme_setup() {
     load_child_theme_textdomain( 'charityhub', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_child_theme_setup' );
```

Parent theme name = charityhub.

What seems to be the problem here ? Language files are not loading...

Comment: Your `function wpdocs_child_theme_setup() {` line needs to refer the the name of your theme, though I don't know the intricacies of the plugin your using so can't suggest exactly what it should be.

Comment: load_child_theme_textdomain( 'charityhub' is referring to the parent theme, called charityhub.